# removing parts of a string that starts and end with a specific word/char Jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a string that i get using .html() and i want to remove the words that start and end with a specific word/char.

example:

`var str = "< li class='classname1 classname2' value='some value' > a sample content </ li >< li class='classname1' value='another value' >another sample content</li >";`

so i want to remove part of the string that has the word [value='] and all the characters before the ['].

the new string should have this value:

`var newStr = "< li class='classname1 classname2' >a sample content< /li >< li class='classname1' >another sample content< /li >";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to remove attributes from an html string. Use jquery to do that instead.

```js
var str = "<li class='classname1 classname2' value='some value' > a sample content </li ><li class='classname1' value='another value' >another sample content</li><li class='classname1' value=\"yet another value\" >another sample content</li ><li><ul><li class='classname1 classname2' value='some nested value' > a nested sample content </li ></ul></li><li>A value='not' in an element</li>";

//Create an element to hold our html
var el = $("<div></div>").html(str);
//get all decendant elements and loop them
el.find("*").each(function(){
  //Remove the attribute
  $(this).removeAttr("value");
});

str  = $(el).html();
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expressions for this Here is a [link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you want to learn more about them.

You can easily use string replace method combined with regular expression to achieve this. Just use this:

```
str = str.replace(/value='.+?'/g,"");
```

In this line `/value='.+?'/g` . means anything that any character or number of characters can follow `value='` except line break, + means more than one occurrence and ? is once or none quantifier. Here is a quick [cheat sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) if you want to learn more about symbols.

As for your specific example here is a [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-n2yhj7?file=index.js) demonstarting this in action you can play around with it.